# Speakers still on when headphones are present (RealTek ALC 262)

Tags: soundcard, headphones

I have a Fujitsu Siemens Laptop Lifebook E8110 with a Realtek ALC 262 soundcard on it.
It worked fined with Ubuntu 10.04, but since I upgraded to the 12.04 version, there is a red light in the audio jack plug and sound still comes out from the speakers when I plug earphones in.

Very inconvenient, especially when working at the library.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Lifebook E8110.
I had the same sound bug on Ubuntu 12.10 OS.

I can switch sound output to the audio jack plug from internal speakers via hda-jack-retask application.

Type

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

in terminal.

Add the appropiate strings according to "Technical details about this PPA" on `https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/hda` link.

Save the file and quit the text editor.

Then type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hda-jack-retask
hda-jack-retask
```

Check the override boxes in "Black Headphone, Front side" and "Black Headphone, Docking station, Left side" sections.

Press "Apply now" and "Install boot override" buttons.

Source forum:

- http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2011/11/29/turn-your-mic-jack-into-a-headphone-jack/